# Using Salesforce Media Objects

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, slds

I want to display an image of a user with text right next to the image. Went through `SLDS` and found `Media Objects` to fulfill my need. Been trying to implement it but the text is always under the image.

Referring to : https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/media-objects/#site-main-content

Here's my code :

```
<div class="demo-only slds-size_3-of-4">
 <div class="slds-media slds-media_responsive">
   <div class="slds-media__figure">
    <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--circle slds-avatar_large">
      <img style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;" alt="Person name" src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/RbPtbsUvcKeWvagdtLktc7s1K1c=/1200x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/MJWZVJVWZQ7U3AVCEN44NMMB4U.jpg" title="User avatar" />
    </span>
 </div>
   <div class="slds-media__body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat minus molestias reprehenderit consequuntur sapiente. Modi veritatis totam accusantium numquam assumenda.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your component as is and it is showing the text next to the image. See below:

[image]

I suggest you check the width of the container. If not, are you open to using [lightning:layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/example)? You can tinker with the widths as you please:

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="false">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="2" mediumDeviceSize="2" largeDeviceSize="2" padding="around-small">
        <img style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;" alt="Person name" src="https://www.washingtonpost.com/resizer/RbPtbsUvcKeWvagdtLktc7s1K1c=/1200x0/arc-anglerfish-washpost-prod-washpost.s3.amazonaws.com/public/MJWZVJVWZQ7U3AVCEN44NMMB4U.jpg" title="User avatar" />
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="4" mediumDeviceSize="4" largeDeviceSize="4" padding="around-small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat minus molestias reprehenderit consequuntur sapiente. Modi veritatis totam accusantium numquam assumenda.
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="12" smallDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="6" largeDeviceSize="6" padding="around-small"/>
</lightning:layout>
```